# Why is inverse slope of the heating curve gives the specific heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I have always been wondering that why the inverse slope of the heating curve gives the specific heat. On the other hand, the regular slope gives the heat capacity at any point.

Thanks,

Comment: No research effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming in this answer that by "heating curve" you mean a plot of temperature (T) on the y axis versus heat (Q) added on the x axis. (some textbooks may call this 'time', but that is unhelpful!)

In this case, we define the heat capacity of the system to be the energy flow that causes a unit temperature change - in other words, *the rate of change of  energy added with respect to temperature.* From calculus, you should know that this is the gradient:

heat capacity = C = dQ/dT = 1/(dT/dQ)

since the slope of the T versus Q graph is dT/dQ, you take the inverse of it to get the quantity you want.

As physical justification, consider what happens for bodies with very low heat capacity or very high heat capacity. A very high (call it infinite) heat capacity object can source or sink a lot of heat without altering the temperature much, so you see a T-Q graph that is nearly flat. Then the slope -> 0 -> 1/infinity.
On the other hand, a very low capacity object changes its temperature very rapidly with only a little heat - the gradient of the T-Q graph is very steep. slope -> infinity -> 1/0 from the right.

Now I'm not sure where you got the idea that heat capacity is the plain old slope, but I'm 98% sure that's wrong. Specific heat capacity is only the heat capacity *per unit mass,* in other words, [heat capacity = specific heat capacity * mass of object.](https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/textbooks/boundless-chemistry-textbook/thermochemistry-6/calorimetry-60/specific-heat-and-heat-capacity-282-1442/) The two are proportional, not equal to the inverse of each other.

Answer (score 0):

A heating curve is a graph of temperature against time as a substance is heated.

Assuming that heat is supplied at a constant rate $\dot h=\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}$ (net of any losses) then we can use the formula relating heat content $\Delta Q$ to change temperature $\Delta T$ to find the slope of the heating curve $\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}$ :
$\Delta Q = mc\Delta T$
$\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}=\frac{1}{mc}\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=\frac{\dot h}{mc}$.

The RHS is a constant. $m$ is the mass of the material being heated, $c$ is its specific heat capacity, and $\dot h$ is the net rate at which heat is being supplied.

The slope **is not** the inverse of specific heat capacity, but it is proportional to it. Neither is the slope the heat capacity, which is $mc$.

In an experiment $\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}$ and $m$ could be measured. $\dot h$ is the power supplied by the electric heater, less a correction for heating losses, which can be estimated from the graph by a clever correction. So $c$ could be calculated.